# Does google glass supports 'kiosk mode'?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, kiosk-mode

I am planning to use the Android GDK for a glass app. Is it possible to restrict the users interaction to that specific app, so all system apps will not be visible? If it is possible, how can you achieve this?

Comment: for what purpose, please provide an example on what you intend to do?

Comment: I'm intrested in it too, I'm developing kiosk mode application, but I can't imaging for what purpose it can be used in Google Glass?

Comment: the purpose is an app for workers in a company. It's not wanted that any glass functionality is used except these called from our app. I guess I will try android kiosk mode as described here http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can on the Enterprise edition; not sure about Explorer. You do it by setting your app as the launcher app. This can be done via ADB.

Per the [Enterprise Developer Guides - Security Guides](https://sites.google.com/a/google.com/glass-partner-dev-program/feature-guides-1/security-guides/home-app)

```
$ adb shell settings put global launcher_package <custom_home_application_package_name>

$ adb shell settings put global launcher_activity <custom_home_application_activity_name>

$ adb shell settings put global is_custom_launcher 1
```